# firebase.com The site cant be reached

Tags: web, web-applications, firebase

we creating a chat app based on firebase, but the problem is that some users can't use the system because their browser can't connect to firebase.
Browser clocks google/facebook login and even when this users try to go to firebase.com - they see the same error - The site cant be reached - Err_connection_reset

Some users have two PC - on one they can use/open the  firebase.com - on other - they cant, though have same provider.

Using different browsers doesn't help - all have same error.
Errors on different browsers:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvfrz.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR9JX.png)

Comment: What we tried to check:
1)Changing provider on PC doesn't help - if it didn't work - it stil doesn't work with other provider, so its locally PC problem
2)Mostly it appears on latest updated windows OS, but a few testers had the latest windows 10 and it all worked good
3)Works good on phones

Comment: One more - it does work when pc working in safe mode - from all browsers - what can it be in new windows that blocks firebase.com?